# Incorrect use of mysqldump, result with strange symbols

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

After a wrong use of parameters in `mysqldump` in conjunction with the database settings I have created a dump, loaded it and then I see errors, mainly in accented characters. Some examples:

| should appear | appears |
| --- | --- |
| space | ÔÇÖ |
| é | ├® |
| É | ├ë |
| ê | ├¬ |

and much more...

After exploring my database table, I can see values like:

```
Agr├®g├® de g├®pgraphie
teacherÔÇÖs
```

The *collation* of the fields in question is `utf8mb4_general_ci` (`VARCHAR` and `TEXT`), same as the *database collation*.

How could those errors be corrected so that the character fields appear as they should?

I have seen a solution [here](https://andy-carter.com/blog/what-the-a-exporting-utf-8-data-from-a-latin1-mysql-table), but in my case I don't have `latin1` encodings in the database.

**Edit:**
`mysqldump` was called from a `PowerShell` script, by the command

```
.\mysqldump.exe -u $dbuser  "database_name" --single-transaction $_ |
Out-File "$BACKUP_FOLDER\${_}$BACKUPDATE.sql" -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: It might be that the issues *can't* be corrected, since changing encoding can in some cases be a lossy process.

Comment: Thank you. Will changing encoding have a result? Could you possibly suggest the encoding change I should try?

Comment: Unfortunately what I mean is that when you made whatever mistake you did, that ended up with your database in this state, I meant that the changes might be irreversible in the sense that you cannot get back the original content. However, is it an option to redo all the steps that lead to this? In which format is the dump file, is it a .sql file? Do you see the same errors in there?

Comment: You say wrong use of parameters with mysqldump, do you know/remember which parameters you used?

Comment: It seems you've managed to run through the 850 or 8xx codepage when encoding the file. If I run it from `"Agr├®g├® de g├®pgraphie"` through the 850 codepage to encode it to bytes, then decode it using UTF8 I get back `"Agrégé de gépgraphie"`. and `"teacher’s"`.

Comment: Looks very nice! I have edited my post adding `mysqldump` params if it makes some sense. Do you mind writing what you mean by _If I run through the 8xx codepage_. Does it include some SQL or other text-encoding transformation?

Comment: I used C#, although I use mysql at work I am afraid I don't know if it can do low-level encoding/decoding like that database-side. I will post my example on dotnetfiddle.

Comment: Here is what I did: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XgLWu8

Comment: Tak! I will try to check it with Python or something but I got the point!

Comment: If your dump file is .sql, and it already contains those errors, it might be salvagable by doing the same kind of encoding/decoding on the whole dump file and writing out a new one. If you have to do surgery on a live database you might have to fix field by field in row by row in a similar manner.

Comment: It may be, however, that you read the properly encoded utf-8 file as cp850 when *importing* into the database, in which case it might be that you have to do the import again. Again, unless you have to do surgery on the live database that is.